# Else If is not working

Tags: java

else if statement doesn't work.  Tells me. "Syntax error, delete the on token "if" delete this token"    If i get rid of the "if" my guessed.add(goat) is unnreachable.  I commented where in the code.     I'm not sure what to try.

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;

import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhraseGameController {

    private Phrase currentPhrase;
    private ArrayList<Character> guessed;

    public boolean doPlayerGuess(Character play) {
        Character goat = Character.toUpperCase(play);
        if (guessed.contains(play)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("the letter was already guessed");
        } else if (String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "the guess should be a letter from A­Z");

            guessed.add(goat); // Unreachable Code
            return currentPhrase.guessLetter(goat);
            return false;

        }

    }

    public PhraseGameController() {
        currentPhrase = new Phrase("This is only a test");
        guessed = new ArrayList<Character>();
    }

    public Phrase getCurrentPhrase() {
        return currentPhrase;
    }

    public void setCurrentPhrase(Phrase currentPhrase) {
        this.currentPhrase = currentPhrase;
    }

    public void setGuessed(ArrayList<Character> guessed) {
        this.guessed = guessed;
    }

    public ArrayList<Character> getGuessed() {
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two pieces of general advice relating to (but not answering) your problem: Firstly, use an IDE. Their syntax and error highlighting (particularly brace matching) are very useful tools, not just for beginners. Secondly, indent your code consistently: the closing brace from the first `if` should be on a separate line.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. I haven't quite learned all the hotkeys yet. I know there is a hotkey for auto indent, but I can't remember what it is at the moment.

Comment: @user3381466 Generally speaking, I wouldn't rely on the auto indent feature (not always anyways), as I find it can make a mess when your lines exceed a certain number of characters. I'd recommend you simply indent and format as you go. I find it easier to stay consistent that way, plus it makes your code easier to read to you (and anyone else) while you're developing.

Comment: @PaulRichter You can configure your indentation options in Eclipse quite extensively. Amongst other things, you can set the maximum line length, under which it won't break your lines in two. Just set indentation up to suit your tastes and rely on it. :)

Comment: @biziclop Ah that's true, fair enough. I never tended to bother with those settings myself, but that is a good point to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a bracket instead of a left parenthesis in your else if.
Also, you have a semicolon instead of brackets, and are missing a right parenthesis.

This:

```
else if {String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]");
```

should be this:

```
else if (String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
```

About your edit:

You have this:

```
        } else if (String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "the guess should be a letter from A­Z");

            guessed.add(goat); // Unreachable Code
            return currentPhrase.guessLetter(goat);
            return false;

        }
```

If the program goes into the else-if, your code:

- Throws an exception (and doesn't continue executing the content of the block).
- Adds goat to guessed (unreachable code)
- returns (unreachable code)
- returns *again* (double unreachable code)

I *think* you were trying to do this:

```
    } else if (String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "the guess should be a letter from A­Z");
    }

    guessed.add(goat); // Unreachable Code
    return currentPhrase.guessLetter(goat);
```

but I'm not really sure.

Also, if you want to throw an exception when the letter is not in the range A-Z you need:

```
else if (!String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
```

When play *doesn't* match [A-Z].

Comment: That worked, but now guessed.add(goat); is unreachable.

Comment: @user3381466 Edit your question with the modifications so we can see whats the problem, please.

Comment: ok, sec.  And thank you BTW.

Comment: @user3381466 I'm not sure what you're trying to do in that method, but take a look.